# No encuentro la dirección estática con Cheat Engine

Tags: c++

Aquí te dejo el código de mi programa en el cual quiero conseguir la dirección estática:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<chrono>
#include<thread>
using namespace std;
typedef struct playerstats {
    int health;
    int balas;
    string name;
    playerstats(int vida,int balas2,string nombre) {
        health = vida;
        balas = balas2;
        name = nombre;
    }
}ps;

int main()
{
    ps plstats(100,100,"Jake Smoker");
    while (true) {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(5));
        plstats.health--;
        cout << "Vida: " << plstats.health << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

He probado usar el **pointer scanner** hasta allí todo correcto hasta que reinicias el programa y los offsets cambian lo cual no me hace que la dirección sea **estática**.

**Primera apertura:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Segunda Apertura:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: los offsets como tal nunca varían, lo que sí cambía es la dirección en memoria. Así un objeto con un offset de 0x10 siempre estará en un offset 0x10 relativo a la dirección que le asigne el sistema operativo al cargar tu modulo. Por ejemplo si el sistema operativo carga tu programa en la dirección 0x00 entonces la estructura estará en 0x10, si el sistema carga el programa en la dirección 0x10 entonces tu esctructura estará en 0x20, pero el offset se mantiene.

Comment: Hay alguna forma de obtener una dirección estática?, en mi caso quiero conseguir la dirección estática de la variable: **plstats.health** alguna idea de como hacer eso ?

Comment: @89jih0 Las direcciones/punteros cambiarán cada vez que ejecutes tu programa, si quieres una dirección estatica, entonces necesitarás usar `static` en tu instancia, de otra forma la memoria que usas en tu estructura será resevada dinamicamente en el stack...

Comment: @89jih0 me temo que no es posible en la forma en que lo estás plantando. Primero en que el compilador puede poner en cualquier orden posible tus objetos. Segundo el enlazador hace relocalizaciones, así que si un objeto tiene un offset 0x100 relativo a un módulo  A éste cambiaría al combinarlo con otro módulo B. Lo único que puedes hacer es examinar manualmente la imagen nativa de alguna compilación de tu programa. Lo que puedes hacer es colocar un placeholder, compilar tu programa, analizar la imagen y finalmente colocar el valor real (con algún editor hexadecimal)

Answer (score 0):

Lectura recomendada:
https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new

Por ejemplo, podrías poner:

```
char memory[sizeof(ps)]; // 1

ps* plstats = new(memory) ps{ 100, 100, "jake Smoker" }; // 2

while (true) {
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
    plstats->health--;
    cout << "Vida: " << plstats->health << endl;
}
plstats->~ps(); // 3
```

1 . Espacio reservado en la stack, suficiente para contener un objeto de tipo ps. Si conoces la dirección específica donde deseas ubicarlo, podrías poner:

```
void* memory = reinterpret_cast<void*>(0x00babe);
```

sólo porque 0x00babe es la dirección donde tú estás seguro que puedes escribir.

2. En las FAQs hay una muy seria advertencia sobre la necesidad de asegurar que la memoria original esté correctamente alineada.
3. Tú eres el único responsable de destruir el objeto.

[pero no dejes de leer la FAQ]

Comment: Primero porque reservar memoria dinamica cuando el está buscando una direccion estatica?, Segundo, porque llamas a un destructor que no existe?... Tercero, Si yo hago `sub esp, 0x4;` será por un tiempo muy corto ya que luego de hacer las tareas tendré que volver el stack a su estado original, el cual la memoria que tratas de explicar no será por stack, será por región... Cuarto: porque no solo hacer un simple `T* x = new T;`?...

Comment: @nikomaster 1-No se reserva memoria dinámica, en ninguno de los dos casos del ejemplo. 2-El destructor existe, implícitamente definido por el compilador. 3-No se pretende tomar un espacio en la stack; en el primer caso del ejemplo se reusa el espacio ya previamente asignado en la stack. 4-Porque eso sería asignar memoria dinamicamente en el el free-store, que entiendo que no es la idea.

Comment: 1- Incorrecto, 2- No tiene sentido llamarlo manualmente ya que ni tu lo has declarado/definido para un proposito y no va con el tema, 3 - Incorrecto, nunca utlizas la memoria del stack en tu caso...  Esto te será de mucha ayuda ya que veo no sabes ni de lo que hablas... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157122/object-creation-on-the-stack-heap

Comment: @nikomaster la primera línea de mi respuesta contiene un link, por favor léelo antes de continuar haciendo el ridículo. Y por cualquier duda, por supuesto que me dará gusto responder a tu pregunta, cuando la escribas, claro está. Y si tu intención es meramente comenzar el año con insultos de troll, olvídate; no me divierten los jueguitos con psicópatas.

Comment: No cambies el tema, mi intención no es armar una discusión, solo estoy diciendo que tu respuesta no va con la pregunta, ademas has explicado las cosas de forma errónea... fin.